# Which Sort is this

Tags: c, sorting

I have written a sorting program which seems like insertion sort but it quite isn't, so my question is which algorithm is this

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n=5,i=0,a[5],j=0,temp=0;
    printf("Enter 5 elements \n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<i+1;j++)
        {
            if(a[i+1]<a[j]) 
            {
                temp=a[i+1];
                a[i+1]=a[j];
                a[j]=temp;
            }
        }
    } 
    printf("\nThe Sorted Array is ");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    printf("%d ",a[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since you wrote the program yourself, wouldn't you know better?

Comment: does it work? it looks like bubble sort, but the swapping is different. it should be swapping `a[j]` with `a[j+1]` not `a[i+1]` and `a[j]`

Comment: I know what it does, just don't know the name of it

Comment: @JabariDash it does work

Comment: @JabariDash This is my first time that I have seen a loop like this, but I think it should work too.

Comment: @njain I name it bubble sort, but it has out of bound error at least, if nothing else.

Comment: @Afshin, oh, but i think it has lot less swapping than the bubble sort does, and ill look into bound error

Comment: @njain bubble sort has 2 different mode. First one is like `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){...}}`, but 2nd one is like for `(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++){for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++){...}}`. Your implementation is similar to 2nd one.

Comment: @Afshin, i look like a fool now, it is bubble, i just compared the two, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sorting algorithm which iteratively compares two consecutive elements and - if they are not in the right order - swaps their position is called *bubble sort*.
The name bubble sort describes the fact that - in the course of execution - the larger elements "slowly" climb up position by position the array like bubbles.

Your algorithm has - in the inner one of the two nested loops - this compare/swap-idiom.

Comment: Just to add another resource, it is quite visual to understand it in [Wikipedia's gif](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordenamiento_de_burbuja#/media/File:Bubble-sort-example-300px.gif) to see how it is working!